# Multiplying values from a dictionary if it exists in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, probability

I am trying to calculate some sentence probabilities.

I have a dictionary that contains some values for different letters:

```
{'a': 0.2777777777777778, 'b': 0.3333333333333333, 'c': 0.3888888888888889}
```

I then have separate sentences in a list such as:

```
['aabc', 'abbcc', 'cba', 'abcd', 'adeb']
```

What i am trying to do is some probability calculations so that it searches the sentence in a list and multiplies the values for example
`aabc` would be `0.2777*0.2777*0.3333*0.388888`

How would i search this list for each independent string and do this multiplication?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: I would love to post a code attempt, if i knew where to even start. Would i split each list item into 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c' then search it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to reduce your sentence into its final probability (note that if a character does not have a probability, I just use 1 to multiply):

```
from functools import reduce

probs = {'a': 0.2777777777777778, 'b': 0.3333333333333333, 'c': 0.3888888888888889}
sentences = ['aabc', 'abbcc', 'cba', 'abcd', 'adeb']

result = [reduce(lambda acc, curr: probs.get(curr, 1) * acc, s, 1) for s in sentences]
print(result) 
# [0.010002286236854138, 0.004667733577198597, 0.0360082304526749, 0.03600823045267489, 0.09259259259259259]
```

Comment: what if i were to use a set unk value for any values that do not appear in my vocab. i.e. if my vocab is just `abc` but unk has a value 0.055. Then `abcd` would be a*b*c*unk

Comment: @godlypython You can change the reduce lambda to `lambda acc, curr: probs.get(curr, unk) * acc, s, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty non-fanciful way of doing it:

```
values = {'a': 0.2777777777777778, 'b': 0.3333333333333333, 'c': 0.3888888888888889, 'd':0.1234, 'e':0.5678}

strings = ['aabc', 'abbcc', 'cba', 'abcd', 'adeb']

for string in strings:
  product = 1
  for char in string:
    product *= values[char]

  print(product)
```

---

### EDIT :

If we want to use check if the dictionary has values, we can do the following and use `unk` instead:

```
values = {'a': 0.2777777777777778, 'b': 0.3333333333333333, 'c': 0.3888888888888889}

strings = ['aabc', 'abbcc', 'cba', 'abcd', 'adeb']

unk = 0.05

for string in strings:
  product = 1
  for char in string:
    if char in values:
      product *= values[char]
    else:
      product *= unk

  print(product)
```

Comment: Lets say d and e wasn't in my vocab file but i want to use a item in the dictionary "unk" for those values, is that possible. i.e. unk = 0.05. Since my vocabulary only includes a,b,c, it will automatically use the value of unk for any d or e letters found

Comment: Yup, I've added an additional response to your follow-up comment.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga true :) Corrected.

Comment: Thank you, could I ask you to run a test and see what output you get? My probability is coming up beyond 1. I think its adding up all the probabilities of all the sentences. I need to keep them seperate. So that each sentence has its own probability

Comment: You can simply your code to remove the `if...else` and replace that with `product *= values.get(char, unk)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a double for loop. The outer `for` would iterate over the sentence list, and the inner `for` can iterate over each letter in the sentence. Python for loop syntax is `for item in iterable_object: <code to run>`. Try using this information and see how far you can get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension and a for loop to do this.

```
def prob(string, prob):
    out = 1;
    probs = [prob[char] for char in string]
    for x in probs:
        out *= x;
    return out
```

`prob` is a dictionary of probabilities and `string` is the string. `in` iterates over each character in the string.